# Wordpress encodes GET parameter

Tags: wordpress, get, base64

I need to pass base64 encoded string as a GET parameter, yes, I know that's a bad idea, but it is necessary. The problem is that I need it like so:

```
http://example.com/?data=c29tZXRoaW5nQA==
```

But it changed the URL to:

```
http://example.com/?data=c29tZXRoaW5nQA%3D%3D
```

Is there a way to do it? Adding this parameter via the query_vars filter fixed the URL, but then always returns the blog page not frontpage.

Answer (score 0):

you can urldecode() your parameter, which will turn it back into the normal one, when you get it. –

So

```
 $returnValue = urldecode('c29tZXRoaW5nQA%3D%3D');
```

Will return

```
 $returnValue = "c29tZXRoaW5nQA==";
```

In short :

```
 $theImage = urldecode($_GET['data']);
```

Should give you your disired string

Comment: I can't - there's a javascript that's using that GET parameter and I can't edit it, that's why I needed it to stay as it is.

Comment: because Javascript has a similar function `decodeURI("yourEncodedUriHere");`

Comment: It's actually decodeURIComponent, but I was aware of it, I just can't edit it as it's not hosted with me.

Comment: same same :) https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp